# C# opening each textfile and reading all text issue

Tags: c#

```
{
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Documents and Settings\g\Desktop\123");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo filex in Files)
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(filex);
            string sharename = Regex.Match(contents, @"\Share+(\S*)(.)(.*)(.)").Groups[2].Value;
        }
    }
```

I just want to be able to open each textfile in this directory, read it all, and then pull the regex i have listed,  With this code can someone point out where my brain fart is?

The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.FileInfo' to 'string' has some invalid arguments
Argument '1' cannot convert frm System.IO.FileInfo to string

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) method expects a filename argument of type string and not [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx):

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(filex.FullName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(filex.FullName);
```

Comment: I think you want FullName instead of FullPath

Answer (score 0):

File.ReadAllText does not accept FileInfo as a parameter. Use instead:

```
String contents = File.ReadAllText(filex.FullName);
```